# Count occurrence of character in list

Tags: python

Python noob here so bear with me..I'm trying to count the occurrences of 'w' in a list using just a for loop and if statement.

Here's my code:

```
items = ["whirring", "calendar", "wry", "glass", "", "llama","tumultuous","owing"]


acc_num = 0

for i in range(len(items)):
  if w in i:
    acc_num = acc_num + 1

print acc_num
```

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.count()` to find all 'w'

```
''.join(items).count('w')
```

To count words with one or more 'w'

```
sum('w' in item for item in items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had some mistakes. Here is your code working:

```
items = ["whirring", "calendar", "wry", "glass", "", "llama","tumultuous","owing"]


acc_num = 0

for item in items:
    if 'w' in item:
        acc_num = acc_num + 1

print(acc_num)
```

Of course there are some issues: if word has two occurences of 'w', do you want to count it twice? And what about capital 'W'?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to iterate through each word in the list:

```
for word in items:
```

To check if `w` exists in a word, you need to do:

```
if 'w' in word:
```

If you don't wrap it with `'`(single quotes), it will be treated as a variable.